# What could be inside this conduit in my kitchen wall?

Tags: vent, conduit

I was having electrical work done in my kitchen and they cut a drywall hole behind my oven, and uncovered this curious conduit or vent pipe or something. It's quite hard, almost cement-like, clearly hollow, and about 7" x 2.5" and oblong. This kitchen is on the 2nd story of my 3 story duplex, and the other kitchen is below it, although it isn't the stove vent from down there, because that goes out the side of the house from the first floor. The location in the wall would put it above the island of the kitchen below, so there isn't a wall for it to travel vertically through down there. I'm perplexed.

[image: photo of conduit behind drywall]

Comment: I'd suggest leaving it alone, anyway. The odds of it being asbestos-cement are pretty high (and this is a case where a borescope or inspection camera might permit you to know that *without* a lab test, as there may be information ientifying it molded into the outside wall.) Some sort of compact flue pipe for a small gas appliance or a plumbing vent are some guesses, but they are just guesses.